# libPhoneNumber-iOS crash on cCode2CNMap method

Tags: swift, libphonenumber

I'm using libPhoneNumber-iOS(0.9.13) inside my app but when running that piece of code the app crashes on the second instruction:

```
let helper = NBMetadataHelper()
let dict = helper.cCode2CNMap()
```

the error stack is the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NBMetadataHelper CCode2CNMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000427500'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e48a12b __exceptionPreprocess 171
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010cb38f41 objc_exception_throw 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e50b024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] 132
3 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e40cf78 ___forwarding___ 1432
4 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e40c958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 120
```

Can somebody give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

The lib has changed, update your code from this:

```
let helper = NBMetadataHelper.cCode2CNMap()
let dict = helper.cCode2CNMap()
```

to this:

```
let dict = NBMetadataHelper.cCode2CNMap()
```